# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.....How to fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. I thought it'll be fun to make a ToDoList Project but it ended up being a lot of work, and still, I can't figure out this error.
firstFile-app.js
this file contains the useEffect..in which I'm having issues

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
//Importing Components
import Form from "./components/Form" 
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";
function App() {
  // All of our states
  const [inputText,setInputText] = useState("");
  const [todos,setTodos] = useState([]);
  const {status,setStatus} = useState("all");
  const {filteredTodos,setFilteredTodos} = useState([]);
  // Use Effect
  useEffect(() => {
    filterHandler();
  }, [todos, status]);
  // Functions
  const filterHandler = () =>
  {
    switch (status)
    {
      case "completed":
        setFilteredTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === true));
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        setFilteredTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === false));
        break;
      default:
        setFilteredTodos(todos);
        break;
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>Afraz's ToDo List</h1>
      </header>
      <Form 
      inputText={inputText} 
      todos={todos} 
      setTodos={setTodos} 
      setInputText={setInputText}
      setStatus={setStatus}
      />
      <TodoList 
      setTodos={setTodos} 
      todos={todos}
      filteredTodos={filteredTodos}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

secondFile-todolist.js
this is the file in which I'm trying to use the function...to render the list

```
import React from "react";
// Import Components
import Todo from "./Todo";
const TodoList = ({ todos,setTodos,filteredTodos }) =>
{
  console.log(filteredTodos);
  return(
    <div className="todo-container">
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {filteredTodos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo 
          setTodos={setTodos} 
          todos={todos} 
          key={todo.id} 
          todo={todo} 
          text={todo.text}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default TodoList;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.....How to fix it?
i have no clue! as I said I'm new to react.

Comment: What does this say - console.log(filteredTodos);

Comment: You need to do some debugging to figure out when `filteredTodos` becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand that useState is asynchronous.

And your   `const {filteredTodos,setFilteredTodos} = useState([]);` iniciate emtpy to only when your pages loades it call ur useEffect that set your switch action to fill ur `filteredTodos` in a setState, which again, is `asynchronous`, and you are imediatily trying to mapping over an array that `possible` has no value yeat, since you dont know when you will receive the values of your switch action.

What you need to do is:

~ Put an condition to only map over your `filteredTodos` when you have a value on it, something like that:

```js
<div>
{filteredTodos.length > 0 && 
filteredTodos.map(todo => ( ...)
)}
</div>
```

Also, pratice naming better yours files name, dont use firstFile-navbar ... secondFile-navbar...

for example: try naming like Navbar, NavbarItems

Comment: This will hide the problem, not fix it. They have initialized `filteredTodos` to an array, so `map` will work just fine regardless of any async code. This means the problem is **after** the async code, they are updating state to `undefined`.

Comment: `map` will work only if `filteredTodos.length > 0`, this is not a way to **hide** the problem since this way it actually **fix** it.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's a way to prevent the error from throwing, but it will only hide their root problem. *map will work only if filteredTodos.length > 0* - this is completely wrong. `map` works perfectly will for an empty array, which is what the OP has initialized their state to be. This means the state is becoming `undefined` after the initial render, and *that* is where they need to fix the problem.

Comment: yes, you are right, map will work in an empty array, so just filtered.Todos !== [] && filteredTodos.map(...)
... if you still tell me that this will only hide the problem, then i have been codding with react wrong.

Comment: `filtered.Todos !== []` this doesn't do what you'd expect. Objects (and arrays) in JavaScript are stored in variables by *reference*, this condition will **always** return true, since you're not asserting that `filteredTodos` is not empty, but that it does not equal the reference of a brand new array. To do what you're trying to do, you'd need to check something like `Array.isArray(filteredTodos)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray))

Comment: What I mean by "hiding" the problem, is that if `map` works on both filled and empty arrays (like we agreed), then that means the *real* bug is the place in the code where `filteredTodos` becomes something other than an array. So while checking if it is an array first will prevent an error, it will not solve the real bug which is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: i understand what you are saying...
But, the said verifications will actually do what i expected, since it actually do what i expect.
And the real bug is what I said, by time he set the state value and tries to map over it, is because his values hasnt updated yet. So that simplos verification should solve the prob.
This is how i have been doing so far, and it works.

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can explain it.... Open up your console in the browser and do `[] === []` or `[] == []`. It will always be false. Just like `filtered.Todos !== []` will always return true.

Comment: i see, you right, now im just more confused why it has been working... or i wasnt since the beginning